How to add green background to the card before removing it. iOS application (Set Game)
I am trying to develop a set game. When certain card gets matched it should the green background should appear behind the card and after some time the card should disappear from the view.
My current solution is following.
I have my dealedCards array that holds my cards in the model. When card is matched with certain rules I am filtering all the matched cards
dealedCards = dealedCards.filter { !$0.isMatched }

problem with this solution is that it immediately deletes matched cards from my view. What I want instead is to apply this green background for some time before removing it.
Zstack {
if card.isMatched {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).fill(.green)
}

cardContent
}

How can I achieve such result that this rounded rectangle gets drawn before my code will delete cards from the view?

Would you provide more code part ?

With the info that you provided, my solution is this:
// The code that sets the card's isMatched variable to true ...

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) {
    dealedCards = dealedCards.filter { !$0.isMatched }
}

If you can provide more info I'll improve the answer.

thanks I've already tried this one. Unfortunately I am having following error: Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter.
Can you specify what kind of additional information can I provide?

Can you provide where the ‘card’ variable comes from and the whole function that makes the filtering (you can cut out the private parts)?

Oh i forgot to ping you @VakhtangSaginadze

you could try using self.dealedCards = self.dealedCards.filter { !$0.isMatched }
to avoid the error.

That doesn't work. I think you run the that code in a mutating function.

Can you make the function not mutating and mark the dealedCards as @State/@Binding/@Published if it's possible?

well nothing is actually private: https://github.com/vsaginadze/SetGame/blob/main/SetGame/SetGameModel.swift
here is the github repo it's on line 78. @Radioactive Yes I do run that code into mutating function. Well my dealedCards is in my model so i don't think that's possible.
ultimately what i trying to is to render green background for a card that is displayed in my view and then remove it from the screen. displayedCards are in my model. card variable in the zstack is just the single card from cards variable that I am passing from my viewmodel. viewmodel gets it from the dealedCards.

Ok, I'm gonna take a look at it and see what I can do.

@VakhtangSaginadze I made it. And bugless. (it definitely didn't take almost 4 hours to make it bugless (: ).

I'm sending a pull request.
